# In vim, writing lisp/clojure code, how to properly indent bindings in let?

Tags: vim, clojure, lisp, indentation

In vim, my bindings of the `let` statement are not properly indent. I get this:

```
(let [language :clojure
               editor :vim]
  "indentation problems")
```

I would like to have `editor` aligned with `language`, like this:

```
(let [language :clojure
      editor :vim]
  "indentation problems")
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried any plugins yet? [This](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2501) claims to 'support indentation' though I can't vouch for it doing what you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since I'm the author of the plugin mentioned in the comment by @edd-steel I can confirm that it does what you need.

Comment: I am using vimclojure but I get the wrong indentation. Do I have to do something special? I indent using `=`.

Comment: @YehonathanSharvit You have to turn indentation on. `filetype plugin indent on` This is independent of vimclojure. Please refer to the extensive vim documentation for more information on filetype plugins. If the setup according to the documentation is correct, but it still doesn't work, please ask on the vimclojure google group for support.